# Fixing string name in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I've just started programming for Android in Eclipse. I used polish letter "ą" in string name and now compiler returns error, since it doesn't know "ą". Unfortunately I can't change the name of this string or delete it. Whenever I try, the system instantly returns to previous version of class R.java.

Is there any way to fix it? Or how can disable auto-correcting of R.java file.

Comment: Can you clarify "in string name"? In the name of the java class file or in the name of a class variable?

Comment: Error I get:   R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

Comment: public static final int PiÄ™kna=0x7f050009;

Comment: Put those informations in the question please.

Comment: R is auto-generated, you can't edit it directly. Find where you defined this string and change it there, then do Project>Clean

Comment: Please explain, very clearly, *exactly* what problem you are having.  If you created the string, why can't you just change it?  I really don' get why you have a problem.  Forget about R.java.  You never have to do anything with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manually modify `R.java`, look for the string you want to change in.-

```
/res/values/strings.xml
```

Comment: hmm... so how can I delete string?

Comment: Just look for the string with that character in the xml and delete it. ADT will automatically update `R.java` for you.